# Is there something like Swarm's Task-Slot in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-swarm

I am working to get an existing application consisting of a bunch of stateless, scalable microservices (and of course also a few stateful ones serving as backends) running on Docker Swarm and Kubernetes. Changing the code of the application is mostly out of the question, so I have to make some existing mechanisms that we have for, e.g., service discovery, work in the Swarm and K8s contexts.

One thing that helped me a lot with getting things up and running with Docker Swarm was the template feature of Swarm's "service create" command (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates), where I can do something like

```
-e my_env_var=foo{{.Task.Slot}}
```

Inside each container that is part of my Swarm service, this will set the env var my_env_var to a value of the form fooX, where "X" is the container's "slot number".
To grasp what a slot number is, consider a service with N instances (i.e., scale=N). Each container occupies one slot, and the slots are numbered from 1 to N.

That way, I can get a ID inside my container that is unique among all currently alive containers of my service, but at the same time, it is NOT totally random. If I scale a service from, e.g., 1 to 5, the five containers in my service will get the slots 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.
If I scale it down to, e.g., 3, two containers will be stopped (e.g., 2 and 4, leaving me with 1, 3, and 5). But if I scale it up again to 5, the slot numbers will (in general) again be 1 to 5 (and even if they were, e.g., 2-6, that is still better than being totally random).

This has proven to be very useful for Swarm-enabling my application and I am desperately looking for something similar in K8s (in particular in the context of K8s deployments, which I am using for our stateless microservices as they seem to be the most suitable K8s concept).
I found the possibility to pass the pod name into the container with

```
    env:
    - name: metadata_name
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Alas, the name of a container is 
a) rather lengthy
b) random (i.e., scaling down and up will NOT reuse names), 
e.g. the pods of a deployment named foo-deployment will be named something like

foo-deployment-64db944b84-bwrxx

foo-deployment-64db944b84-5jf7c

etc.
So as far as I understand, the last five characters are guaranteed by K8s to be unique among all active pods of a deployment, but they are NOT reused (rare collisions nonwithstanding) when scaling up and down.

Is there any mechanism that corresponds to Swarm's "slot" concept?

Regards
PalatinateJ

Answer (score 1):

11 Months late, but here is the solution:

To get stable container (pod) names within K8S you *must* use a `StatefulSet`. `StatefulSets` are designed for applications that must maintain state, however, if you aren't using K8S volumes for state (keeping them ephemeral) you can use `StatefulSets` without an issue. There is a simple process of converting your `Deployment` to a `StatefulSet`:

1. Change your `apiVersion:` to `apps/v1`
2. Change the `kind:` to `StatefulSet`
3. Under `spec:` add the `selector:` tag. This tag will contain everything you use to select the appropriate service. **In addition** you must ensure that any items you have under `spec:template:metadata:labels` match those under `spec:selector:matchLabels` (This will make more sense in the provided example)
4. If you have any sort of update strategy, called `strategy` in a `Deployment`, change this to `updateStrategy`. For future reference, if you do not update this, you will end up with both a `StatefulSet` and a `ReplicaSet` being deployed as K8S is trying to fill the `strategy` and your `StatefulSet` requirements.

After applying these changes, you will have your `StatefulSet` deployed. How do we get task slots from this? The hostname.

Since K8S is maintaining stable pod names, you will have names such as:

```
pod/mypod-0                             1/1     Running   0          10m
pod/mypod-1                             1/1     Running   0          9m
```

when running `kubetctl`. After that, it is a simple matter of parsing the number out of your pod name.

Below is the YAML for a `StatefulSet`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: myStatefulSetName
  labels:
    app: SomeLabel1
    label2: SomeLabel2
spec:
  replicas: 100
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: SomeLabel1
        label2: SomeLabel2
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: SomeLabel1
        label2: SomeLabel2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myPodName
        image: myPod:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: myPodPort
          containerPort: 8080
```

The differences become apparent on a equivalent `Deployment`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myDeploymentName
  labels:
    app: SomeLabel1
    label2: SomeLabel2
spec:
  replicas: 100
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: SomeLabel1
        label2: SomeLabel2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myPodName
        image: myPod:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: myPodPort
          containerPort: 8080
```